# JSON API response line breaks

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am implementing a @ControllerAdvice to help API users understand errors when required fields are missing from the @RequestBody

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    var errorMessage =
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .map(
                fieldError ->
                    String.format(
                        "Field: %s error details: %s",
                        fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage()))
            .collect(joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    var errorResponse =
        generateError(
            BAD_REQUEST, ErrorCode.INVALID_PAYLOAD.getErrorCodeName(), errorMessage);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, errorResponse.getHttpStatus());
  }
```

The issue I am facing is the text in the error response does not match the intended design i.e. I want the message to be built using a line break in between each field validation error.

***collect(joining(System.lineSeparator()))*** should add a line break between each error field.

What I get looks completely different:

```
{
  "apiError": false,
  "errorCode": "INVALID_PAYLOAD",
  "errorMessage": "Field: message error details: must not be blank\nField: contactName error details: must not be blank\nField: contactEmail error details: must not be blank"
}
```

As you can see in the text above - the line break characters are been introduced as per design.

Any ideas about what could possibly be missing here? I have tried viewing the response in both Swagger and CURL in the terminal but the line breaks are not interpreted as I would expect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try This, modify this part-

```
String.format(
                "Field: %s error details: %s \n",
                        fieldError.getField(),fieldError.getDefaultMessage()))
```

I just changed String.format  - I added lineSeparator ( \n ) in the format itself

Comment: I tried this to no avail.

I also tried to use **%n** but that did not work - the response text contains the \n as part of the response string.